# Relation of OData and RedfishSchemas

Tags: web-services, odata

Why industries are moving towards **redfish schemas**? And why specifically **odata protocol** is used for redfish schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why RedFish?
Industry keeps updating its reliance on standards to accommodate latest changes.
Redfish is the new SMI-S.

Why odata Protocol ?
Rest is a philosophy, not a standard. By using odata in response you allow user to write client which enforce data providers to provide data in a manner which is consistent. 
For example: you can write one client which know how to use odata, and this could be used from different extenstion of red-fish APIs